# Examples of Hilbert spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Throughout my education I've encountered the following examples of Hilbert spaces:
 1) the wave functions of a quantum mechanical system are elements of a Hilbert space
 2) in the finite element method for solving PDEs solution can be approximated with functions which are elements of a Hilbert space.

Can you give me other examples where Hilbert spaces are encountered in Math/Science in general?

Comment: Have you looked at the Wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space)? It contains lots of examples.

Answer (score 1):

The space of weight $k$ [cusp forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_form) is a Hilbert space; the inner product is the [Petersson inner product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersson_inner_product).

**Added**: In view of your first example, I decided to add this comment. According to the introduction of the book *[Modular forms and string duality](http://books.google.ca/books?id=zrXvT7lpS_cC&dq=using%20modular%20forms%20in%20theoretical%20physics&hl=fr&source=gbs_navlinks_s)*, it seems that modular forms (of which cusp forms are an important example) are related to different dualities and symmetries appearing in string theory, mainly via the arithmetic of Calabi-Yau manifolds/varieties.

Answer (score 1):

[Reproducing Kernel Hilbert spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space) are fundamental to many machine learning algorithms.